# Right to left tooltip text c#

Tags: c#, winforms, internationalization, tooltip

Using WinForms, I have a string which I want to set into  a ToolTip. The string is separated by lines with `Environment.NewLine`, like so:

```
x.ToolTipText = "aaaaaa" + Environment.NewLine + "bbb";
```

when this string is set to the ToolTip it looks:

```
aaaaaa
bbb
```

But my problem is when I want it to be localized to Arabic and ToolTip does not support the default RightToLeft property, so it looks very bad. I want it to look like:

```
aaaaaa
   bbb
```

Also: `String.PadLeft` does not help!

Any idea?

Comment: Is this an asp.net tooltip (i.e. on an html control) or is this a winforms tooltip?

Comment: If it can't be adjusted you can try to use a ugly way with adding spaces

Answer (score 11):

Second try. Didn't manage to get the previous solution attempt to behave correctly. Found an alternate way by rendering the tooltip using a custom draw method.

Setup the controls:

```
string tip = "aaaaaa" + Environment.NewLine + "bbb";           
toolTip1.OwnerDraw = true;
toolTip1.Draw += toolTip1_Draw;
toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox1, tip);
```

Handle the draw event:

```
private void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Info, e.Bounds);
    e.DrawBorder();           
    e.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.RightToLeft | TextFormatFlags.Right);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's windows forms I guess you have to rely on the unicode control characters to mark the tooltip text as RTL.

```
string myToolTipText = "aaaaaa"+Environment.newLine+"bbb";
char rle_char = (char)0x202B;// RLE embedding 
control.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
control.ToolTipText = rle_char + myToolTipText;
```

Check [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vsarabic/) for more information on authoring RTL applications.

If it's a web application you can check the [w3c authoring RTL applications guidelines](http://www.w3.org/TR/i18n-html-tech-bidi/#tech-tooltips-etc). Basically it comes down to the same solution as for windows forms, adding RLE chars.

Comment: I unfortunately didn't have time to test it out, so I trusted the blog. Found another solution that I managed to get to work. I posted in a new reply.

Answer (score 3):

The ToolTip control already supports this.  The key is that the control for which you display the tip has a right-to-left layout.  This example form demonstrates this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        ToolTip mTip = new ToolTip();
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
            this.RightToLeftLayout = true;
        }
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
            mTip.Show("Hi\nthere", this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, but how does that work with mixed RTL / LTR text?

Comment: This does not work if only RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes is set. I did not test with RightToLeftLayout = true which I cannot use in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Just some general thoughts to give an idea about what's going on: the tooltip class does not draw text like a multiline textbox. The whole tool-tip is considered one line without a binding rectangle, hence RTL vs LTR have no meaning (other then the order of characters within the text).

Result: using normal right-to-left or left-to-right switches either with Unicode RTL codepoints or otherwise, won't help when it comes to aligning: none is applied.

One way out is (ab)using a TextBox and place it nicely over the place of the tooltip. But others have shown prettier ways with owner-drawn tooltips, which is definitely the way to go.

Comment: This answer is defintely wrong. A tooltip text may contain linebreaks which are displayed correctly by Windows.  A tooltip is NOT considered "one line".

Comment: @Elmue, this was back in 2009..., but yeah, it's vague. I think I didn't mean to imply that tooltips cannot _show_ multiple lines (by virtue of using the crlf characters), but that its default behavior is not tailored for bi-drectional stuff. As the top answer showed, you can get the handle of the tooltip and change this behavior, but only for the whole window. It just won't listen to [Unicode RTL marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) etc, disallowing inline bi-directional text.