# create custom tooltip C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I want to create a custom tooltip, with a different style so that when I click on a control (for example a label or a user-control) it appears.

Something similar to what Google does in Google Maps for coordinates.

I tried to create a user-control and show it when user clicked on a label, but it didn't work well.

It is **WinForms**!

I attached a picture of what I want. Thank you in advance!

[image: Tooltip example]

Comment: Why does this need to be a custom tooltip? You can make the standard one look like a balloon with an icon: [see this image randomly stolen from someone else online](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yTJEF.png). Using standard, built-in controls when possible is always a better idea than creating your own. Not only is it easier, but it means you'll introduce a lot fewer bugs and your app will look more like what the user expects to see.

Comment: yes I know that! but First: I want the text in tooltip to be **Right-To-Left** , second I might wanna use Html in Instead of plain-Text!!

Comment: If you use HTML, you can use the styling properties of the html to align your text :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a standard ToolTip but override the painting method so it can appear as you want it, while still behaving like a normal tool tip.

Haven't done this before so I can't provide an example.

EDIT: here is an example: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/119414-custom-tooltip.html

Comment: thank you. I've seen It before. what if I want the tool-tip to be **Right-To-left**?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796312/right-to-left-tooltip-text-c-sharp

Comment: in this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796312 in third answer by "PHeiberg", tooltip text-aling is set to right-to-left(but not in 'IsBalloon' mode!). I want a tooltip like my picture.

Comment: i don't think 'IsBalloon' matters if you overwrite the draw method? Like I said, you should poke around with it a little. I'm sure it's possible.