# Using a designed form for tooltip in c#

Tags: c#, forms, tooltip, designer

Currently I am developing a .NET WinForms application in C#.
I want to use a form created in designer as a custom tooltip for my project's controls.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: [C# How to use ToolTip](http://www.google.com) great examples can be found here.. try it.

Comment: I know how to add tooltips. What I am asking here is a way to use a form created in designer, instead of the typical tooltip. I googled it a lot but I didn't find anything...

Comment: What framework are you using? WPF, Winforms, ??

Comment: [ToolTips WinForms](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tooltip)

Answer (score 0):

One could argue whether this question is a duplicate of [create custom tooltip C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644277/create-custom-tooltip-c-sharp) but as it does not provide an example but just a link I think it's good to list the most important points:

To design your custom `ToolTip` you need to create a new type derived from `ToolTip` and handle the `Draw` event where you draw what you need. Rebuild your project and the `CustomToolTip` should now appear in the `Toolbox`.

```
class CustomToolTip : ToolTip
{
    public CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(this.OnPopup);
        this.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(this.OnDraw);
    }

    // Sets the size of the CustomToolTip.
    private void OnPopup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ToolTipSize = new Size(100, 100);
    }

    // Draws the CustomToolTip.
    private void OnDraw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        // your drawing...
    }
}
```

If you want to use a form for that you'd have create your own logic for showing it on `MouseEnter` etc. or use 3rd party libraries.

Comment: If you have some code you can present it and try to fix it. That's why your question gets downvoted, you didn't show that you've already tried something.