# RTL Arabic text, full stop's at the end not beginning

Tags: c#, winforms, locale, arabic, right-to-left

See below the Testo textbox has the Full Stop correctly at the beginning:
[image]

In the Watch Window and in memory string variables the FullStop is incorrectly at the End:
[image]

The result of this is when I graphically process the string the Full Stop (aka dot) is in the wrong position, how should I move it at start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio to create Windows-based applications that support bi-directional (right-to-left) languages such as Arabic and Hebrew, you will need to set the [Control.RightToLeft Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft?view=netcore-3.1)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether control's elements are aligned to support locales using right-to-left fonts.

[Both of these answers failed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39146491/495455) but helped identify [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1796420/495455).

If you want to get the RTL value in code with variables you have to rely on the unicode control characters to mark them as RTL.

```
var badWhenSetRTLtrue = textBox1.Text;
var goodWhenSetRTLtrue = ((Char)0x202B).ToString() + textBox1.Text;
```

It would make sense to have these as Extension methods:

```
partial class StringExtensions {

private const char LTR_EMBED = '\u202A';
private const char RTL_EMBED = '\u0x202B';
private const char POP_DIRECTIONAL = '\u202C';
private string ForceLTR(this string inputStr)
{
    return LTR_EMBED + inputStr + POP_DIRECTIONAL;
}

private string ForceRTL(this string inputStr)
{
    return RTL_EMBED  + inputStr;
}

}
```

eg:

```
textBox1.Text.ForceRTL();
```

---

For anyone wanting to do this with a web browser and HTML (instead of WinForms) you can set the `direction: rtl;`, eg:

```
<p style="direction: rtl;">טקסט</p>
```

Or either of these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42551367/495455

Comment: "the RTL property is set to true as soon as they select, for instance, a font with arabic script." ...

Comment: Yes, as I said: the layout of the text box is correctly updated (figure 1), my problem is that the in memory string keeps the dot in wrong position (figure 2).

Comment: Well, that's it, but I still have another problem: if I request for the first char, I got the last instead of the first (I got م instead of .).